# Bullet formatting issue in Outlook for Mac using Office Api

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office365api, outlook-for-mac

I am using the following api to replace the composed body to add few tags at the end while sending the email out. So the issue is, if the email body has bullets, it is removing the bullets while replacing the body.

`office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(data, [options], [callback])`

here is the link to see the diff for original body and the body after using the above api. https://www.diffchecker.com/7yKPSHYB

Also added the screenshots below of before and after for compose body.

[image: Original body]

[image: Replaced body after using api]

Comment: This looks like a bug in Mac Outlook. We are working towards fixing it.

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility is this issue fixed or can you pls provide a status on this

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility can you pls provide an update on this.